# Object Oriented design evalution

Tags: design-patterns, uml, modeling, ooad

I have found the following paragraph in [Applying UML and pattern](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Applying-UML-Patterns-Introduction-Object-Oriented/dp/0130925691)

[image]

Now, I am wondering if there is options to evaluate the Object oriented Design?

Note:I use UML (Unified Modeling Language) for Object Oriented Design

Please, suggest any resources that guide me to the evaluation of Object oriented Design

Comment: Evaluate based on what? You can only evaluate in a subjective manner, it doesn't affect your program's functionality if you put everything in one class or throughout an entire hierarchy. You have to decide for yourself if you consider your program easily readable/extensible and when it is, you can say you have a good design.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest asking for an objective evaluation of an OO design may elude you. You can learn amongst other things

- SOLID principles
- Dependency Injection patterns
- More general design patterns ie GOF.
- Domain Driven Design

The design may express certain attributes - loose coupling, encapsulation, cohesive interfaces etc.

Whether the design is 'excellent' is entirely context dependent. Does it allow changes to be made easily? Does the implementation reflecting the design assist the addition of features, support maintenance efforts and lend itself to comprehensibility amongst your team? The team may be more junior and have no knowledge of design patterns and other such practises or the design chosen may be a good fit for your domain.